# Include statement for static library dependency in a static library

Tags: c, gcc, include, dependencies, static-libraries

In my application I use a static library with header file `foo.h`

In my build script I use a gcc `-I` flag `-I./lib`.

The `foo` library is in a directory `./lib/foo`. In my main application I include `foo.h` as

```
#include "foo/foo.h"
```

Now I'm refactoring part of my application as a library, `bar`, that I expect to statically link to another application. This library `bar` depends on `foo`. With my current project layout, I could include `foo` in `bar` as

```
#include "foo/foo.h"
```

However, that would force users of `bar` to place `foo` in a directory called `foo`.

Is the standard thing to do in this case the following?

Add an `-I` flag to the build script that allows including `foo` in `bar` with just

```
#include "foo.h"
```

Comment: Sounds sensible. The `#include` file names (and any hierarchy) should organize *logically*, not by random implementation details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for using folder structures with include files is to prevent collisions with header files of the same name. For instance, lets say I am using a library for encryption, and they have a header file called "status.h". At the same time I want to use a messaging library, and they have also have a header file named "status.h". They cannot coexist in the same directory and if you make the directory an include path it may not know which one you want to include. If you keep them seperate you can include both:

```
#include "encryption/status.h"
#include "messaging/status.h"
```

So the answer to your question depends on how likely you think the name of the include files will conflict with other include files of other libraries. If it will never conflict then what you are suggesting is fine. If it will conflict them make them use the directory.

Happy coding!

Comment: I didn't consider that, thanks. In this case `foo.h` has quite a unique name, so I think I'll go with my proposed solution.